# Off-topic questions cross-posted to Code Review

Tags: discussion, migration, cross-posting, code-review-se

Recently several posts asking for debugging help were cross-posted from Stack Overflow to Code Review after people suggested CR in their comments. Debugging is *off-topic* on Code Review. From our [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> and your question is not about … Trouble-shooting, **debugging**, or understanding code snippets [emphasis added]

Please do not encourage cross-posts, especially off-topic ones. If you feel that a question belongs on Code Review, *flag it for moderator attention* and they will migrate it if necessary. Cross-posting and bouncing questions around the network will only raise tempers and keep questions from being answered.

Example:

- [SO Version with comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5609703/487663) [Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1764/110)

Comment: Examples of such suggestions?  I agree with the sentiment, but it's always nice to have examples instead of just anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @Daniel I edited one in - I have two, but one was author-deleted on both sites. Also see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/308/110 for more background.

Comment: So yes, this is bad, but...two posts? I think every site in the network has gotten two bad migrations at some point

Comment: @MichaelMrozek We only got one really bad migration from Super User to Gaming (and vice versa, haha), but I still made a post about it. I figure (and recommended this Michael as such), that when it comes to subjects that can reasonably be interpretted as on-topic for those unfamiliar with the site (debugging can be easily seen as a topic for a code review), being proactive and seeding the knowledge of the off-topic nature into the experienced Meta users early will go lengths to preventing it from developing into a serious problem.

Answer (score 11):

Just to make it clear:

> Code Review is for *working* code.

If the code in the question has (known) bugs, errors, problems, or otherwise *is not working*, it is not a code review question.

Comment: I added an updated answer. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It has been two years from the last answer. I'll add an updated one.

```
Code Review is for working code whose working OP understands.
```

If you have working code that has been picked somewhere and you want to understand how it works then codereview **isn't** the place for you. Before posting you should know how it works.

I think this was needed as questions about "How X works" have come to codereview.SE incorrectly.